# PSQLException: ERROR: function pg_catalog.timezone error in JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

I am working on an API to use the below native query using the JPA repository. On executing the query by the APi, the application throws the below error :

> ERROR: function pg_catalog.timezone

```
@Query("""
            SELECT SUM(p.total) AS total,
                   date_trunc('day', p.date_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE :zoneId) AS date
            FROM xyz p
            WHERE p.employee_id = :id
              AND p.date_time >= :startDate
              AND p.date_time <= :endDate
              AND p.date_time <= now()
              AND p.status in :statuses
            GROUP BY date
            ORDER BY date DESC
  """, nativeQuery = true)
  fun get(id: Int, zoneId: ZoneId, startDate: ZonedDateTime, endDate: ZonedDateTime, statuses: List<PaymentStatus>) : List<DTO>
```

I went through many posts in StackOverflow , but couldn’t understand the problem here.

Application Details :
Kotlin, Spring, Postgres

Verbose Error:

```
  Caused by:
            org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function pg_catalog.timezone(bytea, timestamp with time zone) does not exist
              Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
              Position: 112
```

Comment: Has ```date_time``` been typecast to match postgres' data type for timestamp?

Comment: @vicki data type of date_time is the timestamp in the DB. Querying with ZoneDateTime should not be a problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding `:zoneId` as binary value (`bytea`) rather than as string, that's why you are getting this error.